# Oracle - Maximum number of sessions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Does anybody know what is the maximum number of sessions allowed in Oracle 11g?

So when I run this command:

```
alter system set processes=??? scope=spfile
```

What is the maximum figure allowed?

Comment: So high that you might want to keep it lower... You should set it to something thats right for your system. Not to some upper limit for all Oracle DBs.

Comment: My Java application doesnt use any connection pooling so I generally get ORA 12519 until some previous connection objects get closed . So please tell me if I make it 1000 would there be an impact anywhere /

Comment: Don't increase the DB limit - fix your application so it doesn't leak sessions anymore.

Comment: I am always on the finally block, closing the oracle object. But i dont know why is the process increasing

Comment: Why has some one given a negative vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the maximum limit on process bucket. Though I can share some information on this. If you exceed this limit, you will face an exception called `ORA-00020 maximum number of processes (somevalue) exceeded.`

This means you cannot connect or any process cannot establish a connection due to either zombies or low number of buckets allocated. You can increase the values of process bucket. This will allow more processes to be connected. But there are some derived parameters which will be impacted.  These derived parameters include `sessions`, `enqueue_resources`, and `_enqueue_hash_chains`. Do read about them and decide.

**Note**: I never suggest you to pass on some high value to find the error code with the allowed value

Comment: Hi We get ORA 12519 each time, on my test system i passed 1000 as a value, which seems OK .. Currenlty 250 is allowed, i think if i allow 1000 then it will be ok . I belive the old connection objects will get closed or will get time out after some time. Right ?

Comment: if the old connect object is not killed then they become zombies. Thast is where you loose process count